# Menu active element with li class istead of a class java script adaption

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu

How is it possible that the menu-item with li class "active" stays open?

At the moment the script is written for the "active" class in the a element. I wonder if it is possible to keep the "active" class in the li element.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#nav > li > a').click(function(){
    if ($(this).attr('class') != 'active'){
      $('#nav li ul').slideUp();
      $(this).next().slideToggle();
      $('#nav li a').removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');
    }
  });
  if($(".active").parent().parent().is('#nav')){
    $(".active").next().slideToggle();
  }else{
   $(".active").parents('ul').siblings('a').click();
  }
 
});
```

```css
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#nav > li > a').click(function(){
    if ($(this).attr('class') != 'active'){
      $('#nav li ul').slideUp();
      $(this).next().slideToggle();
      $('#nav li a').removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');
    }
  });
  if($(".active").parent().parent().is('#nav')){
    $(".active").next().slideToggle();
  }else{
   $(".active").parents('ul').siblings('a').click();
  }
 
});

#nav {
    float: left;
    width: 280px;
}
#nav li a {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
    list-style:none;
}
#nav li a:hover, #nav li a.active {
}
#nav li ul {
    display: none; // used to hide sub-menus
     list-style:none;
}
#nav li ul li a {
    padding: 10px 25px;
}

#nav li.sub {
  padding-left: 35px;
}

ul{
  list-style:none;
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="nav">
  <li class="active"><a href="#">Item 1</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" >Sub-Item 1 a</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 1 b</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 1 c</a></li>
      <li class="sub"><a href="#" >Sub-sub-Item 1 a</a></li>
      <li class="sub"><a href="#" >Sub-sub-Item 2 a</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 2</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 2 a</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 2 b</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 3</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 3 a</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 3 b</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 3 c</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 3 d</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 4</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 4 a</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 4 b</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 4 c</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Thank you in advance for your answers!

Answer (score 0):

By Default load page open first items then put this code

```
$('#nav > li > a:first').click();
```

**inside code in  document ready function**

**Live Demo** [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/patelsumit5192/kkyeu2rs/)

**Update Your Script**

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
  $('#nav > li > a').click(function(){
    if ($(this).attr('class') != 'active'){
      $('#nav li ul').slideUp();
      $(this).next().slideToggle();
      $('#nav li a').removeClass('active');
       $('#nav li a').parent().removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');
      $(this).parent().addClass('active'); // li tag insert active class
    }
  });
  if($(".active").parent().parent().is('#nav')){
        $(".active").next().slideToggle();
  }else{
    $(".active").parents('ul').siblings('a').click();
  }
 $('#nav > li > a:first').click();
});
```

**Snippet Example Below**

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#nav > li > a').click(function(){
if ($(this).attr('class') != 'active'){
  $('#nav li ul').slideUp();
  $(this).next().slideToggle();
  $('#nav li a').removeClass('active');
   $('#nav li a').parent().removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
  $(this).parent().addClass('active'); // li tag inside active class
}
  });
  if($(".active").parent().parent().is('#nav')){
    $(".active").next().slideToggle();
  }else{
   $(".active").parents('ul').siblings('a').click();
  }
 $('#nav > li > a:first').click();
});
```

```css
#nav {
    float: left;
    width: 280px;
}
#nav li a {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
    list-style:none;
}
#nav li a:hover, #nav li a.active {
}
#nav li ul {
    display: none; // used to hide sub-menus
     list-style:none;
}
#nav li ul li a {
    padding: 10px 25px;
}

#nav li.sub {
  padding-left: 35px;
}

ul{
  list-style:none;
  
}
.active
{
  background:#c2c2c2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="nav">
  <li class="active"><a href="#">Item 1</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" >Sub-Item 1 a</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 1 b</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 1 c</a></li>
      <li class="sub"><a href="#" >Sub-sub-Item 1 a</a></li>
      <li class="sub"><a href="#" >Sub-sub-Item 2 a</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 2</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 2 a</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 2 b</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 3</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 3 a</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 3 b</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 3 c</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 3 d</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 4</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 4 a</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 4 b</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 4 c</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I still got an issue: When the "active" element chages it the menu is not adapting. Here for example the second menu element should be open by default: 

https://jsfiddle.net/xszbyLde/

Comment: what  do you want ?

Comment: you want to by default second items open then click here  https://jsfiddle.net/patelsumit5192/xszbyLde/1/

Comment: Thank you. No not exactly. I want that the items are open always when their li class is "active". It should work dynamic.